# »Parochial« und »parochialism« auf Deutsch

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request

Ich übersetze gerade ein philosophisches Buch eines Physikers, in dem die englischen Wörter *parochial* und *parochialism* oft vorkommen. Damit meint der Autor so viel wie *Engstirnigkeit,* oder *einen engen Horizont haben,* allerdings nicht als Charakterzug einer Person, sondern als Eigenschaft einer wissenschaftlichen oder philosophischen Theorie und teils auch als Merkmal eines philosophischen Irrtums. Im Englischen hat das Wort *parochial* zwar auch die kirchliche Bedeutung, die das Wort im Deutschen ausschließlich hat – aber es hat eben auch die andere, etwas weiter gehende Bedeutung der Engstirnigkeit, die sich der Autor zu eigen macht, um die Terminologie in der Philosophie zu erweitern. Da das Wort im Deutschen allerdings nur die kirchenbezogene Bedeutung hat, kann man es nicht einfach direkt ins Deutsche übersetzen, und auch Wörterbücher helfen hier nur bedingt.

Zum Beispiel beschreibt der Autor den Irrtum, wenn man seine eigene Perspektive für universell wahr hält, als *parochial error.* Und damit ist dieser Irrtum ein Beispiel des *parochialism.* Ebenso nennt er eine Theorie, deren Anwendungsbereich stark begrenzt ist, *parochial* – im Gegensatz zu einer Theorie mit sehr hoher oder sogar universeller Reichweite.

Bisher haben wir keine guten Übersetzungen für das Adjektiv *parochial* und das Nomen *Parochialismus* gefunden. *Engstirnigkeit* selbst erinnert zu sehr an Personen. Dem Autor gefällt *provinzlerisch* als Adjektiv besonders gut. Es ist vor allem deshalb vielversprechend, weil Leo [nur eine englische Uebersetzung](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/provinzlerisch) dafür hat: *parochial!* Allerdings gibt es das Nomen *Provinzlerismus* nicht, zumindest steht es nicht im Duden und Google liefert dazu wenige Resultate. (Es gibt zwar *Provinzialismus,* aber dem Autor gefällt dieses Wort in dieser Kombination nicht, da *provinzlerisch* nicht davon abgeleitet werden kann – vermutlich weil die beiden Wörter nicht den gleichen Stamm haben.)

Mir fiel noch ein, dass man als Nomen vielleicht *Provinzlertum* verwenden könnte. Das Wort steht zwar auch nicht im Duden, aber Google liefert dazu viel mehr Resultate als zu *Provinzialismus* und es hat den gleichen Stamm wie *provinzlerisch.* Dabei ist aber die Frage, ob die Nachsilbe *tum* den Anschein erwecken könnte, dass es sich um eine Gruppe von Personen handelt oder ob es so wie im Wort *Reichtum* völlig unpersönlich interpretiert würde (Letzteres wäre vorzuziehen).

Wir könnten nun entweder *provinzlerisch* und *Provinzlertum* benutzen, oder stattdessen das deutsche Wort *parochial* und das eingedeutschte Wort *Parochialismus* als Neologismus benutzen (mit einer Fußnote als Erklärung der Bedeutung und unter Betonung, dass damit nicht die kirchliche Bedeutung gemeint ist). Oder vielleicht gibt es ein noch besseres Wortpaar? Es gibt vielleicht auch noch *Provinzlerei,* aber das erinnert womöglich zu sehr an die Kleinstaaterei des 19. Jahrhunderts.

Comment: Für altmodische Beschränktheit gefällt mir persönlich das Wort "borniert".

Comment: @KilianFoth: Bitte antworte nicht in Kommentaren.

Comment: Es wäre schön, wenn Du einen vollständigen Satz zitierst, in dem "parochial" vorkommt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich erkenne kein Problem damit das Wort

> Parochialismus

als solches zu verwenden. [Verwendungen](https://www.google.com/search?q=Parochialismus&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2yMP54LLpAhWICOwKHcSwA0UQ_AUoAXoECBAQCQ&biw=1680&bih=975) lassen sich mindestens ab 1994, vermehrt ab den 2000er im Deutschen nachweisen. Die Zeitung *Die Zeit* scheint das Wort auch [hin und wieder gerne](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=public;q=Parochialismus) zu benutzen.

Du hast allerdings damit recht, dass [parochial](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/parochial) etwas problematischer wäre, da der Begriff diesen strengen Kirchenbezug hat.

Hier lässt sich allerdings auch Abhilfe schaffen, indem man (wie im Fall Extremismus - extremistisch) das Wort

> parochialistisch

verwendet. Auch auf diese Idee kamen bereits [andere](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=k-q8Xs7uB8WhkwXtp7LACQ&q=%22parochialistisch%22&oq=%22parochialistisch%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1DGGFj_HGCyHmgAcAB4AIABrQGIAZEDkgEDMC4zmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiOhM6S4rLpAhXF0KQKHe2TDJgQ4dUDCAs&uact=5).

Das Wort zu umschreiben mit Engstirnigkeit, Kirchturmdenken, Provinzlertum, beschränktem Denken, etc., finde ich unter dem Gesichtspunkt, dass zumindest der Grundbegriff in der deutschen Literatur bereits verwendet wird, falsch.

Eine einleitende Fussnote beim ersten Gebrauch wäre allerdings trotzdem ratsam.

Comment: Ich wuerde dich gerne im betreffenden Werk zur Anerkennung nennen. Koenntest du mir bitte deinen vollstaendigen Namen nennen?